# Are there any connectors available in mulesoft for connecting Zoho?

Tags: mule, connector, zoho

I have to connect to Zoho Reports from Mulesoft. Are there any mule connectors available or any way to connect Zoho using Mule components?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Zoho Reports connector. For a full list of connectors available you can check out the [Anypoint Exchange](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/). If you want to connect Zoho, you can build your own connector using [Anypoint Devkit](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Anypoint+Connector+DevKit). HTH

Comment: can Janrain Connector be used to connect to Zoho CRM?